# Convert IP Ranges and CIDR to decimal addresses

Tags: php, python, bash, perl, command-line

I have a file that contains multiple IP addresses in multiple formats.

Here's an example of the files:

```
31.14.133.39
37.221.172.0/23
46.19.137.0/24
46.19.143.0/24
50.7.78.88/31
5.79.39.4,5.79.39.5
62.73.8.0/23
63.235.155.210
5.39.216.0,5.39.223.255
64.12.118.23
64.12.118.88
```

Some are in CIDR format, some are ranges, and some are individual IPs.

Here are the 3 different possible formats:

```
63.235.155.210
62.73.8.0/23
5.39.216.0,5.39.223.255
```

I'm wanting to convert all lines into IP decimal ranges. For example, the three-format sample listed above would look like this:

```
1072405458,1072405458
1044973568,1044974079
86497280,86499327
```

The file has around 400,000 lines in it.

I'm okay doing it via command line, Perl, Python or PHP.

Comment: split by line breaks, loop .. not sure which part of this your having an issue with

Comment: you can recognize format by `/` and `,` and then you can use different method.

Comment: Please show us what you are trying to solve your problem.

Comment: BTW: there is standard module [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) to work with IP addresses.

Comment: @Borodin It's a Python module. The OP used tag soup (php, python, bash, and perl).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Ah I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JamesSandzalone: You have a downvote and three votes to close. The problem is that your question's rather entitled, and you seem to imagine us watching daytime TV in the hope that a question will pop up here to relieve our monotony. That's not how it works. Stack Overflow is a place where programmers who have code that won't work despite all their efforts can share it with their peers in the hope of some insight. You don't even have code to share, never mind about doing your best to fix it. If you know Perl, Python and PHP then you are experienced and should be able to come up with something.

Comment: @Borodin I know for a fact that there are a non-trivial number of people who do exactly that. Don't gatekeep people's ability to ask for assistance, just register your disagreement with a downvote, or vote to close, and move along.

Comment: @JamesSandzalone: Please take the [*Tour*](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read and absorb the [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @joeb: The concept behind Stack Overflow is that it should become a kind of *Wikipedia* of useful answers to programming problems. That is why the criteria for closing a question are so strict, and it is an immediate cause for closure if your question has been answered before. Given that vision, questions like *"I don't know how to program but I need to fulfil this specification"* are pretty much useless to the worth of the site. Just because you know people who wish it wasn't that way doesn't make it untrue. Ideally, every question should be crafted to be new and helpful to many other people.

Comment: @joeb: Please take the [*Tour*](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
.

Comment: @joeb: *"Don't gatekeep people's ability to ask for assistance"* The more reputation that subscribers acquire, the more privileges we are given. And those privileges are solely to enable us precisely to *gatekeep* the questions and answers, and relieve the burden on the moderators. There is a continuous queue of items for review, and I can choose to accept, edit, or reject any one of them. If your indolent friends want something to do then the queue is now 1,041 items long, and time spent reducing that would be time well spent.

Comment: Please explain what is the purpose of the result so that those who do not read properly can stop assuming and hence stop deriding others.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Python will do this for you with the help of the [`netaddr`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netaddr) module.

```
from netaddr import IPAddress, IPNetwork

with open("your file.txt", "r") as f:

    for line in f:

        if "/" in line:
            ip_network = IPNetwork(line)
            print "{},{}".format(
                ip_network.first,
                ip_network.last
            )
            continue

        if "," in line:
            first_ip, last_ip = line.split(",")
        else:
            first_ip = last_ip = line

        print "{},{}".format(
            int(IPAddress(first_ip)),
            int(IPAddress(last_ip))
        )
```

Using the three example inputs and the three expected outputs from your question, the above works as expected.

Comment: I can think of a few reasons for your downvote. For instance, code-only answers aren't considered to be the best of answers; also you don't show any sample input or output to show the extent of your testing: what your code produces and what it expects. Most of all thought it's an answer to a *very* specific question and highly unlikely to be of much use to anyone but the OP.

Comment: Apart from being a poor excuse for showing *actual* input and output, your little edit does nothing to explain what you have written and why.